# Why do spreads on type-guarded types cause type checks to be skipped?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

**Question:**

Why don't I receive a compile-time error when I forget to add nested fields to an object of type `T`, when constructing said object using an object spread?

**Example:**

```js
interface User {
  userId: number;
  profile: {
    username: string
  }
}

function updateUsername(user: User): User {
  return {
    ...user,
    profile: {
      // Error (as expected)
    }
  }
}

function updateUsernameGeneric<T extends User>(user: T): T {
  return {
    ...user,
    profile: {
      // No error (unexpected... why?)
    }
  }
}
```

**My own speculation on the answer:**

All I can imagine is that TypeScript allows subtypes to *remove* properties of their supers, making it possible that for some subtype `T` of `User`, the `profile` property might not contain any properties. (If so, I was unaware TypeScript allowed you to do this...)

---

TypeScript Version 4.1.2

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnICumUAkgCYBcyIhAtgEbQDc%20yADlAPYzAA2EangIFi0EHDqDk6MFFABzNgF9cq3DEIgEYYFxBF25OJAzjJEABRio1M1ACUdkjjZQIYQlAPCRAOgCbABo2Ak4efmlfEWQAeljkAFEobihkSzh0ZAgAD3YIHQhyB1DkVQJVdU1tXX1DY1MSCSkAcQgQaGAEAB4AFWycyBByLPsAPmsSal6nZH7fd09vVxiAv2DS8N4BIVKCeOQAOS5slK406w68gshyNeQAdwALAE8AfhKY8rK1IA)

Comment: This is very interesting. We can actually use your generic function to [violate the type system](https://pastebin.com/K76guipw) and get `undefined` in a place where the type is non-`undefined`. This may be a compiler bug.

Comment: yea very interesting that  even `{ ...user, profile: undefined }` is accepted

Answer (score 2):

This has all to do with how the spread is resolved with generic types (see [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/28234)) compared to normal types. If you write the resulting object to a variable, you will immediately notice the difference: for non-generic types, the merged type is inferred as:

```ts
{
    profile: {};
    userId: number;
}
```

which leads to this type being unassignable to the annotated return type `User` that has a required `username` subproperty. This is exactly what the compiler error TS 2322 is telling you:

> Property 'username' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ username: string; }'

Now, the situation with generics is a bit different: the type is actually inferred as an intersection of a subtype of `User` and a `{ profile: {}; }` type:

```ts
T & {
    userId: string;
    profile: {};
}
```

The compiler is ok with that as the intersection is an "extension" of the annotated return type containing all the properties as per the definition of the intersection.

---

Whether this a good behavior is debatable as you can do the following, and the compiler will be none the wiser:

```ts
function updateUsernameGeneric<T extends User>(user: T): T {
  const newUser = {
    ...user,
    userId: "234",
    profile: {
      // No error (unexpected... why?)
    }
  }

  return newUser;
}

updateUsernameGeneric({ profile: { username: "John" }, userId: 123 }).userId //a-ok, "number"
```

---

Since the return type is an intersection of the generic type parameter and the merged properties, you can de-annotate the return type and let TypeScript infer it. Incompatible property types will be correctly inferred as `never`:

```ts
function updateUsernameGenericFixed<T extends User>(user: T) {
  const newUser = {
    ...user,
    userId: "234",
    profile: {
      // No error (unexpected... why?)
    }
  }

  return newUser;
}

updateUsernameGenericFixed({ profile: { username: "John" }, userId: 123 }).userId //never
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnICumUAkgCYBcyIhAtgEbQDc%20yADlAPYzAA2EangIFi0EHDqDk6MFFABzNgF9cq3DEIgEYYFxBF25OJAzjJEABRio1M1ACUdkjjYJ9smhADu95AF5XEWQAOjCbABo2Ak4efmlhYOQAemTkAFEobihkSzh0ZAgAD3YIHQhyB2jkVQJ1AigIMEIoAxAfe1Z1TW1dfUNjUxIJKQBxCHb5BAAeABVCosgQcgL7AD5rEmpZp2R5xPcQT3bfF0DEgjCQyOqbCmoAIgAmAGYAFgeo4NjeASFqgipZAAOS4hSyXBy1naJTKkHIV2Q3gAFgBPAD8VWCtRquDYjWarS8pxYajxhCMJgg9hGEHGk2ACEs2A43F%20CSIwwsjwAUlxkSAHjUIpzoPdkABGV41BzXEgUIA)

Comment: Even that doesn't help typescript detect `return { ...user, profile: {username: undefined} };`

Comment: @smac89 - technically, it can if you consider `never` on the `profile` property itself to be an acceptable workaround (this time the whole `profile` will be of type `never`, see [playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nr2GDN)). Frankly, I agree it does seem like bad behavior. That said, I am yet to find an issue/FR that would talk about that, the PR introducing the feature also does not have any reports regarding the behavior.

Comment: Should I raise this as an issue on GitHub? I like your workarounds, but I can't leave return types off methods due to ESLint rules, and besides, the fact I'd need to remember to do this on a case-by-case basis somewhat defeats the objective: I'll need to be consciously aware that I'm "accidentally" violating the type guard to drop the return type, at which point I'd just fix the code instead (i.e. include the missing properties, and keep the return type) :) Thank you for your in-depth explanation, Oleg!

Comment: @Lawrence - NP! Yeah, may be a good idea to start an issue. I failed to find a raised one on the repo, so unless someone chimes in with a link, this seems to be something new. The behavior is certainly odd, and the workarounds are not very convenient as you mentioned